# Dangerous sendmail behavior?

Tags: security, postfix, sendmail

What's going on here??

```
sendmail cat/etc/passwd
sendmail cat\etc\passwd
sendmail xxxcat/etc/passwd
```

Why in the world does this actually execute the cat command? This works at least on Fedora Core 4 O/S (yes, it's old, but still...) with Postfix.

Is this a known (and fixed) bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested Postfix 2.7.1-1 (Debian) and none of those work as you described. `cat` is not executed. (And to be honest, I can't imagine any possible reason why would `sendmail` execute an arbitrary part of its argument just because it happens to say "`cat`".)

Sure, if you `strace` the `sendmail` process, you might see the file `/etc/passwd` being `open()`ed, but that's completely normal: `sendmail` is querying the real name of your account, in order to fill the `From:` header correctly.

But `strace` does not show *any* calls to `exec*()`, except for the one that launches `sendmail` itself.

---

If you still believe this is a bug,

- try a completely unrelated file instead:

  ```
  sendmail cat/etc/fstab
  ```

  Here `fstab` is something that normally would never be read.
- make sure `sendmail` is not a shell alias or function:

  ```
  $ type sendmail
  sendmail is /usr/sbin/sendmail
  ```
- And update Postfix.

  > (yes, it's old, but still...)

  Never complain about bugs in old software versions unless you have confirmed that they are present in the absolutely latest version too.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.  It turns out in my testing for exploits in another software package, I inadvertently got the other package to actually cat the passwd file into (overwriting) the sendmail binary.  So now when I run the sendmail binary, it is just trying to execute the copy of the /etc/passwd file.  So this was a slight misunderstanding on my part.  My apologies, and thank you for the very nice and helpful answer.